# TYPO3 Custom Page Properties

Tags: php, properties, typo3

I'm trying to make the Publish Date mandatory for my "Article" page type.

I added this code

```
$fields_article = array(
    'starttime' => [
        'label' => 'Publish Date',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'eval' => 'datetime,required'
        ],
    ]
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('pages', $fields_article);
$showItem = "--div--;Page Settings";
$showItem .= ",--linebreak--,starttime";
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['types'][$doktypeArticlePage] = array(
    'showitem' => $showItem
);
```

And this works, but it makes the Publish Date mandatory for all page types. Is it possible to only add the required tag to article page types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to set `eval` based on type, so I'm afraid there's no easy way to do this.

You could most likely do this with a custom eval. See the `Vendor\Extention\*` section in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/latest/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#eval for more information about that.

Alternatively you could create a new required field, which is only shown in your "Article" page type, and use one of the hook in `TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler` to copy its value to the starttime field.

Comment: Thanks! Both answers looks great, I'll try the custom eval first - trying to avoid creating unnecessary fields as I already have plenty.. Thanks again